# Preventing localhosted web application from looking up online resources

Tags: wordpress, performance, optimization, localhost

I am having speed trouble working with my locally hosted wordpress application. This is because it always looks up online resources like fonts.google.com..., api.google.com..., etc, it only when the resources are loaded or fail to.

What would be the best solution to cutting this loading of remote resources?

Would overriding php load time do the trick?

Comment: Any reason you can't host them locally?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably all these resources are being loaded from a CDN, and that would be the way to go. You can improve the performance of your site even further by [pre-resolving the DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/PreResolveDns) of the CDNs.

In your `<head>` tag, you would have something like this:

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.google.com">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//api.google.com">
```

Also consider hosting all of your assets in your own CDN. This way you would only have to deal with a single DNS resolution.

I common pattern is something like `http://www.example.com` for the actual site and `http://assets.example.com` for JS, CSS, and images, fonts, etc.

Here are a few CDN hosting options: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network#Notable_content_delivery_service_providers

Lastly, if you insist in that you don't want any remote resources, just download what you need and host them locally (on the same server running your site).